# uNet - Client cant see server spawned objects

Tags: unity, c#, unity-networking, unet

I'm facing a problem where when I connect with the host, all the towers spawn. After I connect with a client only to find out there are no towers visible and I can walk through them when looking at the host screen.

My tower spawn script ( GameManager.cs ) :

```
public int numberOfDestroyedTopTowers = 0;
public int numberOfDestroyedMidTowers = 0;
public int numberOfDestroyedBotTowers = 0;

public GameObject[] topTowerSpawns;
public GameObject[] midTowerSpawns;
public GameObject[] botTowerSpawns;

public GameObject towerPrefab;

void Start() {
    CmdSpawnTowers();
}

[Command]
void CmdSpawnTowers() {

    for (int i = 0; i < midTowerSpawns.Length; i++) {
        GameObject currTower = (GameObject)Instantiate(towerPrefab);
        currTower.transform.position = midTowerSpawns[i].transform.position;
        currTower.name = "Tower [MID] " + i;
        NetworkServer.Spawn(currTower);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < topTowerSpawns.Length; i++) {
        GameObject currTower = (GameObject)Instantiate(towerPrefab);
        currTower.transform.position = topTowerSpawns[i].transform.position;
        currTower.name = "Tower [TOP] " + i;
        NetworkServer.Spawn(currTower);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < botTowerSpawns.Length; i++) {
        GameObject currTower = (GameObject)Instantiate(towerPrefab);
        currTower.transform.position = botTowerSpawns[i].transform.position;
        currTower.name = "Tower [BOT] " + i;
        NetworkServer.Spawn(currTower);
    }

}
```

The script is derived from NetworkBehaviour and it does have a Network Identity on it (Server Only checked). Also on my towerPrefab I also have a network identity with server only checked.
I have added my tower prefab under the network manager "Registered Spawnable Prefabs".

Comment: Are you sure that you added object you want to spawn into NetworkManager spawnable prefabs? plus this object should have Network identity component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with a [RPC](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html) call

`[Command]` are message from a client to the server a `[ClientRPC]` are messages that are send to all the clients from server

so in order to show all your clients the towers use a rpc call

```
void Start() {
RpcSpawnTowers();
}

[ClientRpc]    
void RpcSpawnTowers() {

    for (int i = 0; i < midTowerSpawns.Length; i++) {
        GameObject currTower = (GameObject)Instantiate(towerPrefab);
        currTower.transform.position = midTowerSpawns[i].transform.position;
        currTower.name = "Tower [MID] " + i;
        NetworkServer.Spawn(currTower);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < topTowerSpawns.Length; i++) {
        GameObject currTower = (GameObject)Instantiate(towerPrefab);
        currTower.transform.position = topTowerSpawns[i].transform.position;
        currTower.name = "Tower [TOP] " + i;
        NetworkServer.Spawn(currTower);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < botTowerSpawns.Length; i++) {
        GameObject currTower = (GameObject)Instantiate(towerPrefab);
        currTower.transform.position = botTowerSpawns[i].transform.position;
        currTower.name = "Tower [BOT] " + i;
        NetworkServer.Spawn(currTower);
    }

}
```